# How to get the latest version of gcc on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: gcc, versions

Hey guys i am new to this just started studying computer science and programming and this is the first time im using linux. So how to get the latest version of gcc on ubuntu or does it make a difference (im using 5.4 right now).

Comment: It depends on what _features_ of _gcc_ you need else simply doing `sudo update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` will give you the latest version supported by Ubuntu 16.04. Ofcousre you can compile the latest if you need it.

Answer (score 6):

The latest version is obtained simply by running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

then installing with

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

This will install `gcc` and other programs you will need. Then of course if you want the latest *you can compile it* yourself. But using the above installation commands you will be able to get the latest for *Ubuntu 16.04 lts*

Comment: Yes, this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Enable this ppa

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

Read here for info

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to just use the one in the repos. Simply open a terminal window and type 'apt-get install gcc' and after entering your root password, you will have the gnu compiler collection!